# What do unlimit and limit do in the context of csh?

Tags: limit, csh, ulimit

I'm running a csh script that calls `unlimit` and `limit` just before running a scientific model. The script looks something like so (truncated for brevity):

```
#!/bin/csh -f
# ...
unlimit
limit
/usr/bin/time $BLD/$EXEC # Where `$BLD/$EXEC` is the path to the model
date
exit
```

Running the script produces the following error:

```
unlimit
unlimit: memorylocked: Can't remove limit
unlimit: maxproc: Can't remove limit
unlimit: openfiles: Can't remove limit
```

Checking `ulimit` from Bash:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63711
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63711
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Trying `unlimit` (without specifying any resources) from csh:

```
$ sudo csh
# unlimit
unlimit: memorylocked: Can't remove limit
unlimit: maxproc: Can't remove limit
unlimit: openfiles: Can't remove limit
```

The output of `limit` from csh, and trying `unlimit` with resources specified:

```
$ sudo csh
# whoami
root
# limit
cputime         unlimited
filesize        unlimited
datasize        unlimited
stacksize       8192 kbytes
coredumpsize    0 kbytes
memoryuse       unlimited
memorylocked    64 kbytes
maxproc         63711
openfiles       1024
# unlimit openfiles
unlimit: openfiles: Can't remove limit
# unlimit memorylocked
unlimit: memorylocked: Can't remove limit
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I am guessing that running `unlimit` is supposed to remove all the resource limitations before running the model, and the output of `limit` is supposed to verify that. Why would the root user not be able to remove the limitations? Is `unlimit` only supposed to be run as root?

Answer (score 2):

ulimit is trying to increase the the maximum usage of those resources above that configured for the entire system by sysctl. Furthermore it's not actually possible to configure Linux with an unlimited number of some resources, such as open files.

Note that unlimiting all resources is not a good idea -- do you really want a few gigabytes of core dump should a model fail? Increase only those resources which are presenting a bottleneck to running the model. Because you can run the model successfully, this suggests that the resources available on your modern machine may be significantly more than on the machine for which the code was originally written.

Comment: So if the model runs successfully without the call to `unlimit` beforehand everything is fine?

Comment: Also, you say "it's not actually possible to configure Linux with an unlimited number of some resources, such as open files", so on Linux, what is `unlimit` supposed to do when not passed a particular resource?

Answer (score 0):

See the `csh` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh), which documents the `limit` and `unlimit` builtins. The `unlimit` is to remove all limit, and the `limit` is the print the current limits. I'm guessing whoever wrote this ran into some sort of resource limit issue at some point and put these in as a defensive means to ensure there were no limits and print what they were if there were any.